# Jasmine: What's the easiest way to define a custom pretty printer for jQuery objects?

Tags: javascript, jquery, testing, jasmine, jasmine-jquery

So the default pretty printer for jQuery values in jasmine isn't very pretty (it prints it as an object, listing every method available).  It'd be much nicer if it just printed it as an array.

I could override `jasmine.PrettyPrinter.prototype.format` to give specific instructions in the case of `value instanceof jQuery` or override `jasmine.isArray_` to return true for jQuery objects, but both of these seem like hacks.

Is there a more natural way of extending the jasmine pretty printer?

Answer (score 1):

@James deBoer solution is the right idea, but I had to modify it somewhat to get it to work:

```
jQuery.fn.jasmineToString = function() {
  this[0].outerHTML;
};
```

`this` is the jQuery object; `[0]` gives you the first DOM element (since jQuery objects are collections of matched elements), and the DOM property is `outerHTML` (note the capitalization).

(There's a good chance that @James has defined his own jQuery.outerHtml() function. See [this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2419749/get-selected-elements-outer-html) for more information).

Answer (score 0):

jasmine.pp will look for a method 'jasmineToString' to be defined on the object.

I extended my jQuery object like so:

```
jQuery.fn.jasmineToString = function() {
  return this.outerHtml();
};
```